# deSolve in R gives incorrect intermediate values

Tags: r, ode

I am having problems with the ode solver in R from deSolve.

I have found that the solver gives non-zero intermediate values for variables that should be always equal to zero. It doesn't look like a problem until I start trying to debug with tests like if(R>0){browser()}, which gets triggered.

My code is below. Thanks in advance!

Ellen

```
library(deSolve)

simpleSIR <- function(t,states,par){
    with(as.list(c(states,par)),{

    S=states[1]
    I=states[2]
    R=states[3] 

    newinfections = beta*I*S

    dS <- -newinfections
    dI <- newinfections - gamma*I
    dR <- gamma*I

    if(R>0)
    {
        print(paste("why is this not zero?",R))
    }

    return(list(c(dS,dI,dR)))   
})}


par=list(beta=0.3,gamma=0.0)

init=c(0.99,0.01,0)

times <- seq(0,500,by = 1)


out <- as.data.frame(ode(y = init, times = times, func = simpleSIR, parms = par,maxsteps=2000))


plot(out[,2],type="l")
lines(out[,3],type="l",col="red")
lines(out[,4],type="l",col="blue")
```

Comment: Why are you checking `R>0` **inside** the function instead of checking the inputs?  But in any case, have a careful look at both answers.

Comment: this is not my code I am working on but a simple example. I think the stiff/non-stiff solver is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the fact that the default method for numerical integration in `ode()` is `lsoda`. This method can switch between solvers for stiff and non-stiff problems. In case you have switches to the stiff solvers, the jacobian is evaluted numerically, which might lead to the numerical errors you see. 
You can see that this might be the reason in the following code:

```
out <- deSolve::ode(y = init, times = times, func = simpleSIR, parms = par,maxsteps=2000)
deSolve::diagnostics.deSolve(out)
```

"[...]14 The number of Jacobian evaluations and LU decompositions so far: 23 [...]"

which corresponds to the number of print messages (23) your original code produces. 
You will get rid of the problem by using a non-stiff solver like RK4:

```
out.rk4 <- deSolve::ode(y = init, times = times, func = simpleSIR,method = "rk4", parms = par,maxsteps=2000)
```

if you insist on using `lsoda`, you might want to try supplying lsoda with the jacobian you calculated analytically.

Comment: This isn't quite clear: if the problem is in fact **stiff** -- or **non-stiff**, according to the documentation,  `lsoda` automatically selects (not switches) the appropriate solver.  Are you suggesting the original equation set somehow switches depending on the current values?

Comment: While I could not find a detailed explanation of the algorithm, my understanding is that the method indeed switches in runtime. ("It uses the nonstiff method initially, and dynamically monitors data in order to decide which method to use."  http://www.oecd-nea.org/tools/abstract/detail/uscd1227). If you have more details on the algorithm, I'd be happy to hear them!

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much. Switching to rk4 does stop this. I didn't realise that lsoda switches solvers.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider accepting answers that worked for you (stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know if you understand the differences between state-variables and parameters.

`R` (in your case) is a state-variable. That means, that at the begin of the simulation (at t = 0) `R = 0`. But with time development this can change. See your state-variable S!

Your parameters beta and gamma, they will not change during the calculations.

Then you can simplify your code. Use this lines instead of your definition of `par` and `init`:

```
par <- c(beta = 0.3, gamma = 0.0)

init <- c(S = 0.99, I = 0.01, R = 0)
```

And now you can remove the following lines, because with `with(as.list(c(states, par))` the names of the parameters and state-parameters are available with their names S, I and R.

```
S = states[1]
I = states[2]
R = states[3]
```

And you can simplify your plot, too:

```
matplot(out[,1], out[,2:4], type = "l", col = c("black", "red", "blue"))
```

Regards,

J_F

Comment: Thanks. The person above answered my question. 'R' is a state variable but it should be equal to zero throughout the simulation as gamma=0.